# Почему запрос долго выполняется при взаимодеййствии с веб-фомрой

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle

У меня есть веб-форма, которая обращается в базе данных к таблице, в которой почти 50 полей и записей свыше 8 миллионов. Бывают случаи, при которых веб-форма долго выполняет запрос объектом `OleDbDataReader` (зачастую при первой загрузке).

Сам запрос не сложный. пример:

```
SELECT distinct CALIBRATION_DATE, NTD_NAME, TECHCHART_NUMBER, SOP_NAME, DIAMETER, THICKNESS, CHANNEL1, CHANNEL2, CHANNEL3,
                    CHANNEL4, CHANNEL5, CHANNEL6, CHANNEL7, CHANNEL8, WORKPLACE_ID FROM USC_OTDELKA
                    WHERE (WORKPLACE_ID=16)and(CALIBRATION_DATE>=TO_DATE('28.10.2019 07:00:00','dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI:ss'))and(CALIBRATION_DATE<TO_DATE('28.10.2019 19:00:00','dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI:ss'))and(EDIT_STATE=0)
                    ORDER BY CALIBRATION_DATE
```

как это выглядит в aspx.cs форме:

```
 OleDbConnection conn = Master.Connect.ORACLE();
    OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT distinct CALIBRATION_DATE, NTD_NAME, TECHCHART_NUMBER, SOP_NAME, DIAMETER, THICKNESS, CHANNEL1, CHANNEL2, CHANNEL3,
                        CHANNEL4, CHANNEL5, CHANNEL6, CHANNEL7, CHANNEL8, WORKPLACE_ID FROM USC_OTDELKA
                        WHERE (WORKPLACE_ID=?)and(CALIBRATION_DATE>=?)and(CALIBRATION_DATE<?)and(EDIT_STATE=0)
                        ORDER BY CALIBRATION_DATE";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("WORKPLACE_ID", WorkplaceID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DATE1", dat1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DATE2", dat2);
    OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Почему вообще происходит такой случай, как долгая выборка запроса в веб-форме? Это уже виноват `OleDbDataReader` ? Проблем из oracle с запросом не наблюдал, а вот в веб-форме бывает долго подгружает. Индексы в таблице присутствуют, работают корректно

Comment: А Dispose вы где-нибудь вызываете (можно неявно, т.е. через using)?

Comment: Да, после того, как я произвел выборку записей, я закрываю `rdr.Close()` и уничтожаю `rdr.Dispose()`

Comment: Во-первых, не ипользуйте `AddWithValue`: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Во-вторых, вместо OleDB следует взять другой провайдер, более специфичный для вашей СУБД. Кстати, какую именно СУБД используете? Судя по названию одного метода - Oracle?

Comment: Да, верно, я использую Oracle

Comment: @ Alexander Petrov а какой провайдер будет более подходящим в моем случае? потому что я использую всегда только OleDB

Comment: `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`

Comment: Используйте ваши советы, как ответ, пожалуйста, это решило мою проблему